# Maven javadoc plugin should be skipped by default but should able to execute when needed

Tags: maven, configuration, pom.xml, skip, maven-javadoc-plugin

I want `maven-javadoc-plugin` to be skipped by default, during the 
`mvn clean install` command, so I have added `<skip>true<skip>` in the `pom.xml`
But I want it to be executed whenever needed, so I am trying something like 
`mvn clean install -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=false`  But it seems that it is overriding this setting with that in `pom.xml` and not executing the javadoc plugin.

What can I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: You can try with profile.

Comment: Can you give me any references or example to see how to configure that?

Comment: I mean how can we by default skip the profile and activate it from command prompt?

Comment: Add javadoc plugin into the profile section only.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a profile for the plugin execution (move it from the normal build generation).  Within the profile, simply state that the plugin should run when you want it.  The idea is that when you do a run without the profile included in arguments, it won't run;  if you include the profile argument, it'll be kicked off:

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Run arguments would look something like:
mvn groupId:artifactId:goal -P profile-1